# Schedule on a certain day of the week

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk

Is it possible to schedule a receive location to run once a week? I can only see to start it between certain dates and at certain times. Seems weird there is no way to run it at 10:00 on Fridays.

Am I missing an option here or is that just not possible? would the only possible way be to use the pollingstatement and do a query that results in 1 if the date is Friday?

[image: schedule]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try use this scheduled-task-adpater like this [scheduled-task-adpater](http://geekswithblogs.net/StuartBrierley/archive/2010/06/23/biztalk-2009-adapters---the-scheduled-task-adpater-receive-location.aspx)

or

if you like more complex way you can try to do somthing with the sdk 
In the SDK directory of your BizTalk installation there is a script called **EnableRecLoc.vbs**

i prefer the first method